# Dispatch group functions not called - how to use dispatch group?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have several functions to retrieve data from firebase. I want an activity indicator to spin until all the data is retrieved.

My problem is that, the functions aren't even started. To search for the mistake I've entered print statements which aren't called.

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadingActInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.loadingActInd.startAnimating()      

    let group = dispatch_group_create()

    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    func loadTweetComplete() {
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }

    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    func loadEventsComplete() {
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.loadingActInd.stopAnimating()
        print("deejayTweetsDictionary = \(deejayTweetsDictionary)")
        print("finished executing")
    }

}

func loadTweetComplete(completionHandler: () -> ()) {

    print("TEST")

    deejayTweetsDictionary.removeAll()

    let usersRef = firebase.child("DeejayTweets").child(passedDJ.objectId)
    usersRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.exists() {

            deejayTweetsDictionary.removeAll()

            let sorted = (snapshot.value!.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "date",ascending: false)])

            for element in sorted {

                deejayTweetsDictionary.append(element as! NSMutableDictionary)

            }

        }

        completionHandler()
    })
}

func loadEventsComplete(completionHandler: () -> ()) {

    print("TEST")

    eventDates.removeAll()

    if passedDJ.objectId != nil {

        let userRef = firebase.child("djBookings").child(passedDJ.objectId)

        userRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.exists() {

                eventDates.removeAll()

                let item = (snapshot.value as? NSMutableDictionary)!

                let allValues = item.allValues
                for element in allValues {

                    eventDates.append(element as! NSMutableDictionary)

                }

            }

            completionHandler()
        })

    }
}
```

The Indicator spins forever and not even the `print("TEST")` statements are called. What am I doing wrong? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Instead of *calling* `loadTweetComplete`, you have defined a local nested function with the same name...

Comment: oh. yeah... that was stupid... well... feel free to answer...

Comment: thank you very much for your help tho

Comment: @MartinR would you like to post that as an answer so I an close this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func loadTweetComplete() {
    dispatch_group_leave(group)
}
```

*defines* a (nested) function. What you want is to *call* the
function with the given completion handler as an argument.
Using the trailing closure syntax that would be

```
loadTweetComplete {
    dispatch_group_leave(group)
}
```